# Creating function points(self) from class Cards

Tags: python

I created a class called Cards and I need to create a function called `points(self)` which returns that card and its associated points. For example the I have three lists I created,

```
Card_rank = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "Q", "J", "K", "7", "A"] 
Cardsuit = ["H", "C", "S", "D"] 
points2 = ["0", "2", "3", "4", "10", "11"]
```

and when the function is called if the input in self is either "2" - "6" + any value from card suit it will print the card with value from `Card_rank` and `Cardsuit` and will give 0 points from `points2` list.

I have tried this:

```
def points(self):
    if self[0] == "2":
        print(self + " Card points is " + self.points2[0])
```

Comment: And what happened then?

Comment: It seems you're complicating it! Why not create a dictionary with cards heights as keys and corresponding values: points_dict = { '2': 2, ... 'J':10,...} . Furthermore, could you add the code of your class, it will help understand how the cards are implemented (especially height).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to define and build a deck of cards with each card having a rank.  With that in mind, you might want to utilize the "index" function to determine the associated point value with a specific card.  Following is an example of what that might look like.

```
class Deck:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        
        self.name = name
        self.Card_rank = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Q", "J", "K", "A"] 
        self.Cardsuit = ["H", "C", "S", "D"] 
        self.points2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11] # Usual point value for games like blackjack
        
    def points(self, card):
        index = self.Card_rank.index(card)
        return self.points2[index]

dk = Deck("Card Deck")

while True:

    selection = input("Enter a card to test or 'Q' to quit ")

    if selection.upper() == 'Q':
        break

    print("The card points are", dk.points(selection))
```

The class was set up as a deck of cards, but the principle should be apparent.  Following is some sample output at the terminal.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Cards$ python3 Cards.py 
Enter a card to test or 'Q' to quit A
The card points are 11
Enter a card to test or 'Q' to quit J
The card points are 10
Enter a card to test or 'Q' to quit 10
The card points are 10
Enter a card to test or 'Q' to quit 8
The card points are 8
Enter a card to test or 'Q' to quit K
The card points are 10
Enter a card to test or 'Q' to quit Q
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Cards$
```

You might give that a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: 'Q' to quit is perhaps not the best choice ;)

Comment: You are right.  Had a "DUH" moment there.  Better get another cup of coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a namedtuple which describes individual cards:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Card = namedtuple("Card", ["suit, rank", 'points'])
```

then for example:

```
c1 = Card('H', 'Q', 11)
print(c1.points )
```

Yields: 11